# How to power cycle a USB port on windows?

Tags: windows, usb, command-prompt

I have USB device which I connect it to a windows PC the software on this USB device has a special combination keys which makes it enter in to the Boot loader mode but in order to enter it into a boot loader mode the device must be power cycled after the special combination keys have been entered. Now we no longer want this functionality. I did write a code to enter the combination keys but one thing I am unable to do is to power cycle the USB port itself without the need of manually unplugging the USB device and then plugging it back in. Is there a way to power cycle the USB ports on windows.

EDIT: I want to do this remotely

Thanks

Comment: See [How to control power to USB ports using batch](http://superuser.com/questions/715888/how-to-control-power-to-usb-ports-using-batch)

Comment: @AlexK. I tried it most of them talk about additional hardware which I do not want to do. I want to power cycle the board remotely

Comment: Could be you're looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbioctl/ni-usbioctl-ioctl_usb_hub_cycle_port